# Continuous mapping of Borel sets

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If I have a continuous mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ would it be true that for a Borel set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and a borel set $f^{-1}(A)$ a set $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)$ is also a Borel set?

And if I have an intersection or union of open sets (say finitely many) in $\mathbb{R}$ would the inverse $f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}A_n)$ of those sets be equal to $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}f^{-1}(A_n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $f$ is continuous, then in particular it is Borel - that is, the preimage of any Borel set is Borel. So certainly $f^{-1}(A)$ is Borel if $A$ is Borel. But recall that the complement of a Borel set is also Borel - so $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is also Borel, and so $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus A)$ is Borel.

The union-of-sets question you can answer for yourself. Recall that, by definition, a point $x$ is in $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k)$ if and only if $f(x)$ is in $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$. Recall also that a point is in $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$ if and only if it's in $A_k$ for some $k$. So $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k)$ is the set of those $x$ so that $f(x) \in A_k$ for some $k$. What does it mean for a point to be in $\bigcup_{k=1}^nf^{-1}(A_k)$?

Comment: That its in one of the preimages $f^{-1}(A_k)$?

Comment: Right, now keep going. What does it mean to be in one of the preimages $f^{-1}(A_k)$?

Comment: Okay, I think I see the point. We have $x \in f^{-1}(A_k)$ that means our $f(x)$ is in one of the $A_k$ thus is in their finite union, right? And what if we has a countable union?

Comment: The only difference between a countable - or uncountable - union and a finite union is the size. Did the size have anything to do with any of these definitions?

Comment: The size didn't come up anywhere, so apperently this should work. thank you very much, I just get confused proving things for unions of set especially generalizing stuff for countable unions, to me they seem very tricky.

Comment: That's a common gut instinct - infinity behaves very oddly in many situations. Trust your reasoning, though - infinity doesn't mess things up for no reason. When moving from the finite case to the infinite case, look for a *reason* something would break down - if there isn't one, the argument works fine.